# Getting Subversion 1.6 working with OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, svn, homebrew, macports

**EDIT : I solved my issue simply by upgrading my SVN client. It doesn't seems to create any conflicts or problems of any kind with my SVN 1.6 server. But if you need information about why SVN 1.6 wasn't working, you should check out the duplicate link. I started to dig around and I found the exact same issues that the guy described.**

The question is pretty talking by itself. I'm actually trying to get subversion 1.6 (any minor version is fine I guess) work on OS X El Capitan. Actually, I can't upgrade to any latest version of svn, as my repository is actually running in 1.6 and we can't upgrade yet.

I searched for ports and home brew versions, but they are not distributing 1.6 version, the oldest I managed to get this way was 1.7. So I searched my way through dark deep 2nd page of Google, and i found this: I checked out an [old revision of MacPorts repository](http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/devel/subversion), the revision 76647 which contains svn 1.6.16. I managed to get it installed through MacPorts. I see it activated and installed through :

```
$ port installed subversion 
The following ports are currently installed:
  subversion @1.6.16_0 (active)
```

But when I try to do a checkout of any repository I have, I get the following error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I searched through stack overflow (and others), but the only guys who seems to solved it, did it by upgrading to 1.7 (or newer).

May someone have a solution to get it working? Let me know if there is a way for me to give you more informations (`--verbose` option can't be used while using `svn checkout`).

Or maybe there is a version of svn client that is retrocompatible with 1.6 servers without messing up the whole file system ?

Comment: There is no need to use 1.6 or 1.7 client. Use an up-to-date Subversion 1.8 or 1.9 client.

Comment: You were right, indeed that doesn't affect server-side copy, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am mistaken, but AFAIK, you can use a newer svn client version with a repository in an older format without any problem.

The only thing is, starting with svn 1.7, you need to manually `svn upgrade` your checked out *working copy* to the new storage structure, or simply re-checkout the repository with the new client once. You do not need to upgrade the *repository* itself, so this does not affect your colleagues.

EDIT: Apologies for not answering the actual question (how to get 1.6 working on OSX 11)

Comment: I was thinking about using a Mac client (like Versions). I took the opportunity to give it a try. It seems to work very well using SVN 1.7 inside the software.